# Is there any third party date picker for angular 5 application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 5 and I am working task which should have a date picker .So I am looking for a date picker rather than having the Browser's default date picker .

Here I have tried many third party tools but nothing is working for me .

Can anyone suggest me a simple and effective date picker .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap Datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) always did a good job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for date picker. It is simple and efficient.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker